# video not showing in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

this is going to be lengthy but I will try to keep it as short as possible.
the problem I am facing is that I have embedded a video in my site, but some how it only works in firefox I want it to work in IE and chrome as the *background* of the page.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/modernizr.custom.26584.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/video_background.min.js"></script>

<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted"
volume="0"> 

<source src="Cosmic cloud_h.264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
<source src="Cosmic cloud_h.264.flv" type="video/flv"> </video>
<source src="Cosmic cloud_h.264.ogv" type="video/ogv"> </video>
<source src="Cosmic cloud_h.264.webm" type="video/webm"> </video>
<title>title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css"</head>
<body>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $("body").video_background({  format:"16:9",
                           mp4:"videos/Cosmic cloud_h.264.mp4" ,
                           flv:"videos/Cosmic cloud_h.264.flv" ,
                           webm:"videos/Cosmic cloud_h.264.webm" ,
                           ogv:"videos/Cosmic cloud_h.264.ogv" ,
                           formatMobile:"16:9",
                           mp4Mobile:"videos/mobile/Cosmic cloud_h.264.mp4" ,
                           flvMobile:"videos/mobile/Cosmic cloud_h.264.flv" ,
                           ogvMobile:"videos/mobile/Cosmic cloud_h.264.ogv" ,
                           webmMobile:"videos/mobile/Cosmic cloud_h.264.webm" ,
                           loop:"true",
                           autoplay:"true",
                           muted:"false"   });
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you so much.

Comment: simply right click on the video tag portion in page.And you will see options to play the video

Comment: lol in IE it just takes a few seconds to load and is showing so thats confirmed, also in chrome its just a black screen even if i tell it to play same things, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The BigVideo jquery plugin plays background video and is ridiculously simple to use.

http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

It works smoothly across the browsers you've mentioned.